# Why picture appears above text even when I added it below the text

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, diagrams, paragraphs, format-files

I wrote following code and I added picture below the text but it appeared above it. can anyone please suggest fixes, Thanks.

```
\subsection{Bloch sphere}
Bloch sphere is graphical representation of Qubit. It’s a unit sphere on the surface of which all possible pure states exists and all the mixed states exist inside it. |0⟩ and |1⟩ occupy the north and south pole of the sphere, respectively. And, |+⟩ and |-⟩ states lie on the equator.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 0.7\textwidth]{Fig2.png}
    \caption{Bloch sphere Representing qubits}\cite{jazaeri2019review}
    \label{ }
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please format your code using the code option, and add a preamble and a `\begin{document}` and an `\end{document}` :) It will help people more easily answer your question.

Comment: Try writing `\begin{figure}[h]` instead of just `\begin{figure}`. I haven't tested it myself, but using an option may help. This website may be useful: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Inserting_Images#:~:text=The%20options%20are%20as%20follows%3A%201%20Use%20the,graphic%20and%20places%20it%20inside%20a%20figure%20environment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Pseudonym123 no. Using[h] does not fix the position (and can even harm). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/2388 about how to influence float parameters.

Comment: Thank you, @UlrikeFischer. I was just offering what I would have looked into, were I in this position. I am actually quite inexperienced with float parameters, so thank you for the elaboration :) - I was simply trying to help give him a potential path to figuring this out.